# PSQL connection alias

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is it possible to create a connection alias for psql?

For example, instead of having to type out:

```
psql --host=pr-gis-db --username=peregrinius --port=5432
```

I just type

```
psql pr-gis-db
```

And it connects with pre-configured settings.. Maybe prompts for password instead of storing it.

Comment: You could write a bash script which accepts a command line parameter.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thank you this is what I was after.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

following the instructions here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html

Create/update the file ~/.pg_service.conf

```
[pr-gis-db]
host=pr-gis-db
user=peregrinius
dbname=gis
port=5432
```

to run the alias connection

```
psql service=pr-gis-db
```

Note: you can also overwrite parameters in the file if you specify them when calling the service.

```
psql service=pr-gis-db -U dbadmin
```

Comment: Here is a bash completion snippet that will allow `psql service=foo<TAB>` to complete these service names: https://gist.github.com/horsepunchkid/8b4e8c37136caea39710371efb5542c6